# Jasmine Headless Webkit spec file running before assets?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jasmine

To run the spec files & assets as coffee script, I decided to go with jasmine-headless-webkit. I believe I have everything installed correctly, but perhaps something wrong in my jasmine.yml file:

```
src_files:
  - spec/support/javascripts/jquery-1.7.2.js
  - app/assets/javascripts/application.js
helpers:
  - helpers/**/*
spec_files:
  - "**/*_spec.*"
src_dir: 
  - vendor/assets/javascripts
spec_dir: spec/javascripts
```

When I run the command, I get three errors, all along the same lines:

```
Editor should have an array named tables. (/Users/aaronmcleod/Documents/awesome_model/spec/javascripts/editor_spec.js.coffee:20)
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: AwesomeModel
```

The AwesomeModel variable is my hash I'm using that I export to the window object. I then attach things like the Editor class to it. Any ideas as to why this isn't defined? Here's my spec file if it helps:

```
fixture_text = ->
  "Company has_many:Employee\n" +
  "  id : int\n" +
  "  name : varchar\n" +
  "Employee belongs_to:Company\n" +
  "  id : int\n" +
  "  name : varchar\n" +
  "  phone : varchar\n" +
  "ComplicatedTable-Name\n" +
  "  id : int"

class DummyPane
  constructor: ->
    @viewport = {}

  clean_up: ->

describe "Editor", ->

  it "should have an array named tables", ->
    editor = new AwesomeModel.Editor(fixture_text())
    expect(editor.tables).toBeDefined()

  describe "#parse_table_names", ->
    text = fixture_text()
    editor = new AwesomeModel.Editor(text)

    it "tables should be of three length", ->
      editor.parse_table_names()
      expect(editor.tables.length).toEqual(3)

    it "the first table name should be 'Company'", ->
      editor.parse_table_names()
      expect(editor.tables[0].name).toEqual("Company")

    it "the third table name should be 'ComplicatedTable-Name'", ->
      editor.parse_table_names()
      expect(editor.tables[2].name).toEqual("ComplicatedTable-Name")

  describe "#add_columns", ->
    text = fixture_text()
    editor = new AwesomeModel.Editor(text)
    editor.parse_table_names()

    describe "first table", ->
      it "the first table should have two columns", ->
        editor.add_columns()
        table = editor.tables[0]

        expect(table.columns.length).toEqual(2)

      it "the first column of first table should be named 'id : int'", ->
        editor.add_columns
        table = editor.tables[0]
        expect(table.columns[0].name).toEqual('id : int')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer by utilizing guard. No changes to the spec file, a few minor changes to the jasmine.yml file. Here's my gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.0'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer'

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'haml-rails'

gem 'jquery-rails'

platforms :ruby do
  gem 'pg'
end

platforms :jruby do
  gem 'jruby-openssl'
  gem 'activerecord-jdbcpostgresql-adapter'
end

group :test, :development do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'jasmine'
  gem 'guard'
  gem 'guard-coffeescript'
end
```

My guardfile:

```
# A sample Guardfile
# More info at https://github.com/guard/guard#readme

guard 'coffeescript', input: 'spec/javascripts', output: 'spec/javascripts'
```

Jasmine.yml

```
src_dir: 
  - assets/javascripts
src_files:
  - assets/application.js
helpers:
  - helpers/**/*
spec_files:
  - "**/*_spec.js"

spec_dir: spec/javascripts
```

I changed the assets path to not use the local folder structure, but the asset path properly.

To run this, just run `guard` in one tab, and `rake jasmine` in another. As you save spec files, the .js version will be compiled by guard.